# getClientBehaviors() method is not getting inherited from UIComponentBase while extending UIInput

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, custom-component, mojarra

I am currently reading Core JavaServer Faces(3e) book.

I am trying to run the ajax spinner code from the 11th chapter of the book.

I am using Oracle enterprise pack for eclipse, weblogic 10.3.5 server & Mojarra impl.

But the UISpinner class is showing the following error message:

> “The type UISpinner must implement the inherited abstract method
>   ClientBehaviorHolder.getClientBehaviors() “

However, as per the jsf spec - UIComponentBase class implements the getClientBehaviors() method which is inherited by the UISpinner class. Still why I am getting this error? Please help.

Here is the UISpinner class implementation:

```
package com.corejsf;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.faces.component.FacesComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehavior;
import javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorHolder;
import javax.faces.convert.IntegerConverter;

@FacesComponent("com.corejsf.Spinner")
public class UISpinner extends UIInput implements ClientBehaviorHolder {

   private static List<String> eventNames = Arrays.asList("click");

   public UISpinner() {
      setConverter(new IntegerConverter()); 
         // to convert the submitted value
      setRendererType("com.corejsf.JSSpinner");  
         // this component has a renderer
   }

   public String getDefaultEventName() { return "click"; }

   public Collection<String> getEventNames() { return eventNames; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have going on is a little tricky. You are right that UIInput extends UIComponentBase, which does implement getClientBehaviors(). However, you are implementing ClientBehaviorHolder, which has a public getClientBehaviors() method.

The class you are implementing MUST have that method and apparently it can't come from the class you are extending. What I would do is go ahead an implement that method with a simple empty return value like:

```
return Collections.emptyMap();
```